# Sharepoint (MOSS) 2007 - Central Admin Issue

Tags: central-administration

We have SharePoint 2007 installed. We are facing issue in central admin when we try to do any operation related to web applications.

Below are the issues noticed:

•   When we tried to change web application in right dropdown (in content database, Manage web application features etc. ) we get a blank page.

[image]

•   We will get ‘The web page can not be found’ (404) error when we click on Web application in Web Application List.

[image]

Steps tried to fix the above issues :

•   Restarted the below services

   Windows SharePoint Services Administration

   Windows SharePoint Services Timer

   Windows SharePoint Services Tracing

   Windows SharePoint Services VSS Writer

•   Ran the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration wizard and restarted the server.

•   Cleared the cache present in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config

•   Checked is there any orphan entry present in Content databases by using the STSADM commands (where result showed no orphan entry present)

Comment: You blanked out the entire URL on the 404 page. You don't have to show the base part of the URL, including the port, but knowing what was attempted to be loaded may help someone assist you. Please add that information if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have updated the images. Looking forward for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The are two options here.

1. You can run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard from another app server in the farm and choose to move Central Admin to the new server during the configuration.
2. You can reprovision Central Admin via psconfig.exe with the adminvs switch e.g.

   `psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 8080 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm`

For more detail on psconfig, see [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093.aspx).

**SUPER IMPORTANT:  You MUST be logged into the server as the original install account for both options which, in 2007 was usually the spadm account.  Doing this under your personal admin account usually leads to unpredictable results.**